# How to set the index of a Series from another Series

Tags: python-3.x

I have two Series. One looks as follow:

```
2016-01-04 00:00:00+00:00    194.972
2016-01-05 00:00:00+00:00    195.379
2016-01-06 00:00:00+00:00    192.838
2016-01-07 00:00:00+00:00    188.220
```

The date is its index.

Another Series looks as follow:

```
0     186.679615
1     186.409242
2     185.783922
3     185.598504
```

What I want is set/replace the index of the second Series with the index from the first Series so it will look as follow:

```
2016-01-04 00:00:00+00:00    186.679615
2016-01-05 00:00:00+00:00    186.409242
2016-01-06 00:00:00+00:00    185.783922 
2016-01-07 00:00:00+00:00    185.598504
```

If this is not possible, maybe could I add the column from the second Series to the first one sothat it will look like as follow?

```
2016-01-04 00:00:00+00:00    194.972  186.679615
2016-01-05 00:00:00+00:00    195.379  186.409242
2016-01-06 00:00:00+00:00    192.838  185.783922 
2016-01-07 00:00:00+00:00    188.220  185.598504
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas Series and DataFrames Indexes can be changed by assignment.
Thus, if your two Series are called `s1` and `s2`, then

```
s2.index = s1.index
```

assigns `s1`'s index to `s2`. Note that the two Series must have the same length or else an `ValueError` will be raised.

---

Alternatively, to form a DataFrame using `s1` and `s2`, you could use

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'s1': s1.values, 's2': s2.values}, index=s1.index)
```

Note that `s1.values` returns a NumPy array of `s1` values *without the index*. 
To form this DataFrame it is important to use `.values` here so that that Pandas does not try to align the values from `s1` and `s2` based on their respective (and differing!) Indexes.

---

To illustrate difference, consider:

```
import pandas as pd
s1 = pd.Series(range(4))
s2 = pd.Series(range(4), index=list('ABCD'))
df = pd.DataFrame({'s1': s1.values, 's2': s2.values}, index=s1.index)
#    s1  s2
# 0   0   0
# 1   1   1
# 2   2   2
# 3   3   3

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'s1': s1, 's2': s2}, index=s1.index)
#    s1  s2
# 0   0 NaN
# 1   1 NaN
# 2   2 NaN
# 3   3 NaN
```

In the second example, `pd.DataFrame` aligns values from `s1` and `s2` based on their respective indexes. `index=s1.index` crops the rows so that only values with index labels from `s1.index` are included. Since `s2` has no values with these index labels, the values are filled with `NaN`s.